# Query Join 2 tables based on specific conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 MYSQL tables.

[My 2 tables in a simple way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JA2p.jpg)
The first table, stores the conversations, second table stores the messages related to conversation in the first table, I need to write a query to view each conversation from the first table and only the last received message (order by msg_time) from the second table.

I have tried this, it works but gives the oldest message from second table:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_conversations inner JOIN 
tbl_messages ON tbl_messages.convers_id = tbl_conversations.id 
GROUP BY id ORDER BY tbl_messages.msg_time DESC";
```

And also I need to display the conversation that has the most recent message on top, I mean to display the conversations according to the time of their last messages. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please edit you question with code you have tried and table not on photo.

Comment: We don't want to see just a "requirements dump". We want to see proof that you researched/toiled, and we want to see your best attempt, minimal yet sufficient sample data, and your exact desired result set.

Comment: Use inner join between both the tables and also limits with order desc

Comment: @SimoneRossaini - if anybody ever asks you "why no screenshots?", you can point them [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)! To the OP, you could take a look also! Please provide tables (`SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G`) and some sample data (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...);`) - either here or as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you get `ambiguous` error
because `id` in `group by` must be write like this `tbl_conversations.id`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_conversations inner JOIN 
tbl_messages ON tbl_messages.convers_id = tbl_conversations.id 
GROUP BY tbl_conversations.id  ORDER BY tbl_messages.msg_time DESC";
```